# VBA: Get the data/value/content of the last row

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to get the value/data/content of the selected last row through this method?  How do I get it. Thank you.

```
Dim WhatChapter As String
WhatChapter = InfoForm.Chapter

If WhatChapter <> "" Then
    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
End If
```

Comment: Use the `Value` property of whichever cell you want (e.g. `Cells(lastRow, "A").Value` )

Comment: Thank you so much @YowE3K. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your question have many possible approach.
What I usually do is, locate the lowest range in a worksheet and do an end `xlUp` like,

```
Dim rLastNonBlankCell as Range
Dim LastRow as Long
Set rLastNonBlankCell = Sheet[x].Range("A1048576").End(xlUp)
LastRow = rLastNonBlankCell.Row
```

Comment: You should not hardcode the row count! Different Excel versions do have different row counts. Always use something like `LastRow = Worksheet("sheet1").Range("A" & Worksheet("sheet1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` or wrap it into a `With` statement to shorten it. Also you don't need to set the range which is shorter.

Comment: @peh Ah! Thank you sir. Am I correct to assume that this will return an error if the code runs on excel 2007 and earlier?

Comment: Yes, yours is only working in Excel 2010 and later. Mine would work for earlier versions too.

Answer (score 0):

I found a easy way to solve this problem.

If you want to get VALUE from lastRow you can use the following  way :

```
Dim rows As String
Dim value As String
Dim concat As String

rows = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row

Dim a As String
'Column
a = "A"
concat = a & rows
'Value in last low is below
value = Range(concat).value

MsgBox (value)
```

I hope that this solution will be helpfull for others